# sed: get 2 lines from a single one

Tags: sed

I have a list of filenames as `id-datetime.txt`, one each line, where id is always the same and datetime is ordered.

I need first and last datetime so having a sed_script in a variable `$script` that grabs it I can do

```
sed -nr "1 $script p; \$ $script'
```

I get

```
datetime (oldest)
datetime (newest)
```

also working with a single-file list.

Now what if I'd like to get also another line with also the id like

```
id
datetime (oldest)
datetime (newest)
```

is there an (easy) way of editing line 1 twice so it gives 2 separate lines?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I got it

```
1 {
    #hold the line
    h
    #extract id
    s|^([0-9]{6}).*|\1|; p
    #put line back again
    g
    #get datetime
    $sed_str
}
```

this part of the sed script will print (and edit) the first line twice

Comment: +1 for "getting it", and utilizing sed beyong s/x/y/p :) ... It will be handy for other sed tasks, as it certainly works here, but for your **specific** example (above), you don't really need to use the hold space. You can simply insert \n between \1 (ID) and \2 (datetime)... as per Gilles example (where he uses the line ending as the \n)

Answer (score 3):

So you want to extract some data from the first line and the last line? Just use a single command for each, printing two lines the first time.

```
sed -n -e '1s/^\(.*\)-\(.*\)\.txt$/\1\
\2/p' -e '$s/^\(.*\)-\(.*\)\.txt$/\2/p'
```

You might find awk clearer if wordier.

```
awk -F- '{gsub(/\.[^.]*$/,"");
          dt=$2}
         NR==1 {print $1; print $2}
         END {print dt}'
```

Or Perl.

```
perl -l -ne 's/\.[^.]*$//;
             /^(.*)-(.*)$/ or next;
             print $1 if $.==1;
             print $2 if $.==1 || eof'
```

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't this suppose to parse the file twice, one for each `-e`? I was already using two different sed calls and wanted to optimize using a single pass, I found how to do it using hold buffer. +1 for `awk` and `perl` alternatives, I'll `time` them to see which is faster, thank you.

Comment: @neurino: sed is a streaming editor, it never backs up in the input file. Multiple `-e` arguments are equivalent to specifying a multiline script.

Comment: @Gilles: I profiled on a dir with 5000+ files in it: `time ls -1 | sed -nr -e '1 p' -e '1 p; $ p'` takes 159ms, `time ls -1 | sed -nr '1 {h; p; g; p}; $ p'` 118ms (-25%).

Comment: @neurino: I found the times to be effectively the same when I used your version (which still needs a second expression for the last line)... Gilles hasn't used two expressions for your {h; p; g; p}.. He too has used a single expression, with a newline char, to create the two lines you were after....  I did, howerver, need to add a backslash to the end of the first line, so that the newline created by pressing Enter was treated literally as '\n'.

Comment: @fred: _> I found the times to be effectively the same_. Do you mean _the same_ execution time for both statements or _the same_ as I stated (-25% for using `{h; p; g; p }`) ? I repeated profiling several times and had constant results on my linux box.

Comment: @neurino.. perhaps I misunderstood your meaning. but it seems that you are trying to compare a **single -e** {h;p;g;p} expression to **two -e** expressions to produce the 2-line output you want (for the oldest time).. My comment was in the context of pointing out that Gilles' method has bypassed the need for two -e expressions for the oldest-date, and it is nominally the same "speed" ... Even so, I don't get the results you mention; Here is a link to the test script and the results I got for 100 itterations over 5000 files:  http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/605022/

Comment: @fred: ok, I got it, don't know why I get different speeds...